# Hiding and showing elements based on <select> value and whether related input field is empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

:)

Really enjoying building my first javascript web app. It's a simple thing really - a stats calculator for wow classic which is coming out next year.

So the idea is that you choose a class, enter some values in the inputs. As each value is changed (I used change and keyup for this), the resulting 'calculations' also appear below the form. Happy I have got this far and just wanting to take it a step further.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ejnLbyug/
I am using vanilla JS and jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
        <option  value="Warrior">Warrior</option>
         <option value="Paladin">Paladin</option>
        <option value="Mage">Mage</option>
        <option value="Shaman">Shaman</option>
        <option value="Warlock">Warlock</option><option value="Priest">Priest</option><option value="Druid">Druid</option><option value="Hunter">Hunter</option>
       <option value="Rogue">Rogue</option>
       </select>
    <p></p>
<br>
    Stamina
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="stamina" placeholder="0" />
    <br>
    Strength
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="strength"  placeholder="0"/>
    <br>
    Agility
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="agility"  placeholder="0"/>
    <br>
    Intellect
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="intellect"  placeholder="0"/>
    <br>
    Spirit
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="spirit"  placeholder="0"/>

    <p></p>
</form>

<p id="classheader">
</p>

Stamina:

<span id="staminaresult">
</span>
<br><br>
Strength:

<span id="strengthresult"></span><span id="strengthblockresult"></span>
<br>
<br>
Agility:

<span id="agilityresult">
</span><span id="agilitycatresult">
</span>
<span id="agilityrangedresult">
</span>
<span id="agilitycritresult">
</span>
<span id="agilitydodgeresult">
</span>
<span id="agilityarmorresult">
</span>
<br>
<br>
Intellect:

<span id="intellectresult">
</span>
<span id="intellectcritresult">
</span>
<br>
<br>

Spirit:

<span id="spiritmanaresult">
</span>
<span id="spirithealthresult">
</span>
<br>
<br>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$("form").on('keyup change', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedValue =

// Stamina

$('select').val();
    var stamina = $('input[name=stamina]').val();

// Force class selection

    if (!selectedValue) {
        return alert('You must choose your class');
    }

// Stamina calculation

        stamina = stamina * 10;

// Print class selection

      document.getElementById('classheader').innerHTML = (selectedValue);

// Stamina result   

  document.getElementById('staminaresult').innerHTML = ('+' + stamina + ' Hit Points')

// Strength - attack power calculation

$('select').val();  
      var strength = $('input[name=strength]').val();

    if (selectedValue === "Warrior") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Paladin") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Mage") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Shaman") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Warlock") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Priest") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Druid") {
        strength = strength * 2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
        strength = strength * 1;
    }else {
        strength = strength * 1;
    }

// Strength - subsequent DPS calculation

$('select').val();  
      var strengthdps = $('input[name=strength]').val();

      strengthdps = strength / 14;
      strengthdps = strengthdps.toFixed(2);

// Strength - attack power result

document.getElementById('strengthresult').innerHTML = ('+' + strength + ' Melee Attack Power' + ' (+' + strengthdps + ' DPS)')

// Strength - block calculation

$('select').val();  
var strengthblock = $('input[name=strength]').val();

    if (selectedValue === "Warrior") {
        strengthblock = strengthblock / 20;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Paladin") {
        strengthblock = strengthblock / 20;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Shaman") {
        strengthblock = strengthblock / 20;
    } else {
        strengthblock = 0;
    }

strengthblock = strengthblock.toFixed(2);

// Strength - block result

document.getElementById('strengthblockresult').innerHTML = (', +' + strengthblock + ' Block')

// Agility - attack power calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agility = $('input[name=agility]').val();

    if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
            agility = agility * 1;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Rogue") {
            agility = agility * 1;
    } else {
        agility = 0;
    }

// Agility - subsequent DPS calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilitydps = $('input[name=agility]').val();

      agilitydps = agility / 14;
      agilitydps = agilitydps.toFixed(2);

// Agility - attack power result

  document.getElementById('agilityresult').innerHTML = ('+' + agility + ' Melee Attack Power' + ' (+' + agilitydps + ' DPS)')

// Agility - cat attack power calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilitycat = $('input[name=agility]').val();

    if (selectedValue === "Druid") {
            agilitycat = agilitycat * 1;
    } else {
        agilitycat = 0;
    }

// Agility - cat subsequent DPS calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilitydpscat = $('input[name=agility]').val();

      agilitydpscat = agilitycat / 14;
      agilitydpscat = agilitydpscat.toFixed(2);

// Agility - cat attack power result

  document.getElementById('agilitycatresult').innerHTML = (', +' + agilitycat + ' Melee Attack Power (in Cat Form)' + ' (+' + agilitydpscat + ' DPS)')

// Agility - ranged attack power calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilityranged = $('input[name=agility]').val();

    if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
            agilityranged = agilityranged * 2;
    } else {
        agilityranged = 0;
    }

// Agility - ranged subsequent DPS calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilitydpsranged = $('input[name=agility]').val();

      agilitydpsranged = agilityranged / 14;
      agilitydpsranged = agilitydpsranged.toFixed(2);

// Agility - ranged attack power result

  document.getElementById('agilityrangedresult').innerHTML = (', +' + agilityranged + ' Ranged Attack Power' + ' (+' + agilitydpsranged + ' DPS)')

// Agility - crit calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilitycrit = $('input[name=agility]').val();

    if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
            agilitycrit = agilitycrit / 53;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Rogue") {
            agilitycrit = agilitycrit / 29;
    } else {
        agilitycrit = agilitycrit / 20;
    }

agilitycrit = agilitycrit.toFixed(2);

// Agility - crit result

  document.getElementById('agilitycritresult').innerHTML = (', +' + agilitycrit + '% Crit')

// Agility - dodge calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilitydodge = $('input[name=agility]').val();
      if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
            agilitydodge = agilitydodge / 26.5;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Rogue") {
            agilitydodge = agilitydodge / 14.5;
    } else {
        agilitydodge = agilitydodge / 20;
    }

agilitydodge = agilitydodge.toFixed(2);

// Agility - dodge result

  document.getElementById('agilitydodgeresult').innerHTML = (', +' + agilitydodge + '% Dodge')

// Agility - armor calculation

$('select').val();  
      var agilityarmor = $('input[name=agility]').val();

      agilityarmor = agilityarmor * 2;

// Agility - armor result

  document.getElementById('agilityarmorresult').innerHTML = (', +' + agilityarmor + ' Armor')

// Intellect - mana calculation

$('select').val();  
      var intellect = $('input[name=intellect]').val();

 if (selectedValue === "Rogue") {
            intellect = 0;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Warrior") {
            intellect = 0;
    } else {
    intellect = intellect * 15; }

// Intellect - mana result

  document.getElementById('intellectresult').innerHTML = ('+' + intellect + '  Mana')

// Intellect - crit calculation

$('select').val();  
      var intellectcrit = $('input[name=intellect]').val();

 if (selectedValue === "Warlock") {
            intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 60.6;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Druid") {
            intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 60;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Mage") {
            intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 59.5;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Shaman") {
            intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 59.5;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Priest") {
            intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 59.2;
    } else if (selectedValue === "Paladin") {
            intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 29.5;
    } else {
        intellectcrit = intellectcrit / 20;
    }

intellectcrit = intellectcrit.toFixed(2);

// Intellect - crit result

  document.getElementById('intellectcritresult').innerHTML = (', +' + intellectcrit + '  % Crit')

// Spirit - mana regen calculation

$('select').val();  
      var spiritmana = $('input[name=spirit]').val();

 if (selectedValue === "Druid") {
            spiritmana = 15 + (spiritmana / 5);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
            spiritmana = 15 + (spiritmana / 5);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Paladin") {
            spiritmana = 15 + (spiritmana / 5);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Shaman") {
            spiritmana = 15 + (spiritmana / 5);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Mage") {
            spiritmana = 13 + (spiritmana / 4);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Priest") {
            spiritmana = 13 + (spiritmana / 4);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Warlock") {
            spiritmana = 8 + (spiritmana / 4);
    } else {
        spiritmana = 0;
    }

spiritmana = spiritmana.toFixed(2);

// Spirit - mana regen result

  document.getElementById('spiritmanaresult').innerHTML = ('+' + spiritmana + '  Mana per Tick')

// Spirit - health regen calculation

$('select').val();  
      var spirithealth = $('input[name=spirit]').val();

 if (selectedValue === "Druid") {
         spirithealth = 0.09 * (spirithealth + 6.5);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Hunter") {
            spirithealth = 0.25 * (spirithealth + 6);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Paladin") {
            spirithealth = 0.25 * (spirithealth + 6);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Shaman") {
            spirithealth = 0.11 * (spirithealth + 7);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Mage") {
            spirithealth = 0.1 * (spirithealth + 6);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Priest") {
            spirithealth = 0.1 * (spirithealth + 6.5);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Warlock") {
            spirithealth = 0.07 * (spirithealth + 6);
    } else if (selectedValue === "Warrior") {
            spirithealth = 0.8 * (spirithealth + 6);
    } else {
        spirithealth = 0.5 * (spirithealth + 2);
    }

spirithealth = spirithealth.toFixed(2);

// Spirit - health regen result

  document.getElementById('spirithealthresult').innerHTML = ('+' + spirithealth + ' Health per Tick')

  });
</script>
```

I would now like to:

1. Hide  elements in the HTML if the user has not input anything into the related input box. For example, as it is now, when a user leaves the 'Stamina' box empty, it still shows the result for 'Hit Points' as +0. Instead of showing that +0, I'd rather just hide it completely if that input box is left empty. How could I do this for all the 'results' that are printed with inner.HTML? I have tried the following for the Stamina input:

> ```
> if (stamina === 0) { return;
> } else {
>   document.getElementById('staminaresult').innerHTML = ('+' + stamina + ' Hit Points')
>  }
> ```

...but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

2. Hide certain  elements in the HTML based on an if, else if, else condition which is dependent on the 'class' that is selected in the  box. For example, the only class that can use 'cat form' is the Druid, so I don't want the user to see this inner.HTML unless they have selected Druid in the  box.
3. When that is done ^ I'd like to make use of jQuery animations to fade in quick and fade out quick whenever  are ordered to appear or disappear by the changing inputs of the user.
4. Finally, I made an error state when the user hasn't selected anything in the drop down. This is good because you need to select a class for the calculator to work. So, the user clicks in an input box, types a letter and boom! They get an error message saying they must select a class. All good so far. However, when they then go to click the  dropdown in order to fix their mistake, they are hit with a second, identical error message, which is not great. I think this is because the script thinks that by clicking on the  dropdown, a keyup is registered and then the error is called again. How can I stop this rather annoying bug from happening? I want the first error to pop up, as it does, but I don't want the second error to appear right when the user is trying to correct themselves.

Thanks very much for reading,
Teeb

Comment: Please, one question at a time. I like how you've shown an attempt for #1. What about your attempts for #2 and #3? I suggest splitting your question into several individual questions, dissecting your code, and focusing on a particular area so that it's [_minimal_ while still _complete_ and _verifiable_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey TrebuchetMS, okay I’ll do that with my attempt for each one. Thanks for the advice!